# Valor não entra em condicionais

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>
    <style>
 h2{
     font-size: 15pt
 }
div#Type{
margin-top: 20px
}
    

div#percs{
margin-top: 20px
} 


div#res{
margin-top: 20px
}
    </style>
<head>
    <body>
<h1>Calculando Consumo</h1>
<h2> Informe o tipo de carro (A, B e C). Informe o percurso rodado em km e calcule o consumo estimado, conforme o tipo, sendo (A=8, B=9 e C=12) km/litro</h2>
<div id='Type'>Tipo de Carro</div>
<input type="text"name="Carro"id="Carro" > 
<div id='percs'>Percurso em km</div>
<input type="number"name="Percurso"id="Percurso"> 
<input Type="button"name="calcular"id='Calcular'value='calcular' onclick="calcular()">
<div Id=res>Resultado</div>

        <script>
        
        //6) Informe o tipo de carro (A, B e C). Informe o percurso rodado em km e calcule o consumo
        //estimado, conforme o tipo, sendo (A=8, B=9 e C=12) km/litro
       calcular ()
       { 

        var carro = document.getElementsByName("Carro")
        var percurso = document.getElementsByName("Percurso")
        var perc = Number.parseInt(percurso.value)
        var consumo = document.getElementById('res');


        if(car == 'A'){
            consumo = perc / 8;
           consumo.innerHTML=('o seu carro consumiu ', consumo,' litros');
        }
            if(car == 'B'){
                consumo = perc / 9;
                consumo.innerHTML=('o seu carro consumiu ', consumo,' litros');
            }
            if(car == 'C'){
            consumo = perc / 12;
            consumo.innerHTML=('o seu carro consumiu ', consumo,' litros');
        }




    }
        </script>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: onde a função "calcular()" está sendo chamada?

Comment: `if(car == 'A')`, quem é `car`? Essa variável parece não existir...

Comment: Porque o `<body>` está dentro do `<head>`?

Comment: A função esta sendo chamada com o comando 'onclick no' input#calcular do botao

Comment: a variável car estava escrita errada devido a uma modificção que eu fiz no codigo porem mesmo depois de muda-la para carro continua nao rodando

Comment: quanto ao body estar dentro do head foi um erro meu que ja consertei porem o erro continua

Comment: O que acontece é que quando eu clico no botão calcular ele nao executa nada

Comment: `carro` será um elemento do DOM, referente ao `<input>`. Se precisa comparar o valor dele precisará fazer `carro.value`

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente vc deve estar aprendendo Javascript, então, tem muitos erros tanto no seu **Html** quanto no seu **js**

- **`Html` =>** div com `id` resultado sem **" "** no atributo id
- **`Js` =>** `document.getElementsByName` retorna uma **nodeList**, ou seja, um array de elementos Html, que para acessá-los necessita inserir um índice. Não pegou os valores com **value**. Está utilizando a mesma variável para fazer a porcentagem e escrever no Html. Faltou concatenar corretamente a variavel de consumo com a string resultado e o principal faltou também declarar a palavra **`function`** para a função.

```js
function calcular() {

  var carro = document.getElementsByName("Carro")[0].value;
  var percurso = document.getElementsByName("Percurso")[0].value;
  var perc = Number.parseInt(percurso)
  var resultado = document.getElementById('res');
  var consumo;
 
  if (carro == 'A') {
    consumo = perc / 8;
    resultado.innerHTML = 'o seu carro consumiu, ' +consumo+  ' litros';
  }
  if (carro == 'B') {
    consumo = perc / 9;
    resultado.innerHTML = 'o seu carro consumiu, ' +consumo+ ' litros';
  }
  if (carro == 'C') {
    consumo = perc / 12;
    resultado.innerHTML = 'o seu carro consumiu, ' +consumo+ ' litros';
  }

}
```

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 15pt
}

div#Type {
  margin-top: 20px
}

div#percs {
  margin-top: 20px
}

div#res {
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculando Consumo</h1>
<h2> Informe o tipo de carro (A, B e C). Informe o percurso rodado em km e calcule o consumo estimado, conforme o tipo, sendo (A=8, B=9 e C=12) km/litro</h2>
<div id="Type">Tipo de Carro</div>
<input type="text" name="Carro" id="Carro">
<div id='percs'>Percurso em km</div>
<input type="number" name="Percurso" id="Percurso">
<input Type="button" name="calcular" id="Calcular" value="calcular" onclick="calcular()">
<div Id="res">Resultado</div>
```

Comment: Sim comecei a aprender agora JS pela internet e estou com bastante dificuldade rsrsrs, mas muito obrigado me ajudou muito!

Comment: Complica um pouco mesmo no começo, mas, depois melhora um pouquinho ;) Sucesso aí.

Answer (score 0):

Haviam alguns erros como... calcular precisa ter function antes para dizer que é função, variável car nas condicionais e elemento com nome Carro... enfim, erros simples =D

Sorte aí, espero ter ajudado.

o código correto seria o de baixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Teste</title>

  <style>
    h2{
        font-size: 15pt
    }
    div#Type{
    margin-top: 20px
    }
        

    div#percs{
    margin-top: 20px
    } 


    div#res{
    margin-top: 20px
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <h1>
    Calculando Consumo
  </h1>

  <h2>
    Informe o tipo de carro (A, B e C). 
    Informe o percurso rodado em km e calcule o consumo estimado, conforme o tipo, 
    sendo (A=8, B=9 e C=12) km/litro
  </h2>

  <div id='Type'>
    Tipo de Carro
  </div>

  <Select id="Carro">
    <option value="A">Carro A</option>
    <option value="B">Carro B</option>
    <option value="C">Carro C</option>
  </Select>

  <div id='percs'>
    Percurso em km
  </div>

  <input type="number" name="Percurso" id="Percurso"> 

  <button name="calcular" id="Calcular" onclick="calcular()">
    Calcular
  </button>

  <div id="res">
    Resultado
  </div>

  <script>
    function calcular ()
    { 

      var carro = document.getElementById("Carro").value;
      var percurso = document.getElementById("Percurso");
      var perc = Number.parseInt(percurso.value);
      var consumo = document.getElementById('res');

      if(carro == 'A') {
        consumo.innerHTML = `o seu carro consumiu ${perc / 8} litros`;
      }
      if(carro == 'B') {
        consumo.innerHTML = `o seu carro consumiu ${perc / 9} litros`;
      }
      if(carro == 'C') {
        consumo.innerHTML = `o seu carro consumiu ${perc / 12} litros`;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```